# how to set maxDate in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Hi I have included given code

```
 $('.start').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: "+0D",
        dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy",
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
          $('.end').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
      });
      $('.end').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: "+0D",
        dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy",
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
          if (selectedDate.length >1)
            $('.start').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
          else
            var selectedDate = new Date();
                selectedDate = selectedDate.format('mm-dd-yyyy');
            $('.start').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
      });

      <input type="text" name="start_date" class="start">
      <input type="text" name="start_date" class="end">
```

When I click on start it allows me to select till todays date(i.e 03-08-2015) but when i go to end with out selecting start and then come to start then it takes me to 2010 i.e it starts calender showing from jan 2010. Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors should be strings. I think what you are trying to do is to set boundaries for start/end dates so that they make sense. I would use selectors based in ids and set `maxDate` for `start` and `minDate` for `end`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#start').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        maxDate: "+0D",
        dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#end').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $('#end').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: "+0D",
        dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#start').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});


<input type="text" name="start_date" id="start">
<input type="text" name="end_date" id="end">
```

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/9q4Lkrth/

Comment: What did you expect instead?